# How to define macros only for c compilers?

Tags: c, macros

I am building a application in c and c++. I have header file st.h in which i defined two macros min and max.
I need to compile these macros only for .c file calls and   for .cpp file  calls it should not preprocess  these macros.It should preprocess for .c file calls for below macros. What is the option to undefine these macros only for.cpp files??

```
#define max(a, b)  (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#define min(a, b)  (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))
```

Comment: You should use seperate headers. C and C++ are different languages.

Comment: `#ifndef __cplusplus` ?

Comment: In MSVC, `stdlib.h` already contains the macros `min ` and `max`, which are controlled by `#ifndef __cplusplus ... #endif`